# Add another point to existing graph Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, graph

[[image]

So far I know that there are limitation regarding to Opencv Plotting real time graph. So I currently modifying the code from histogram graph to plot a real time graph. Below will be my code. But the result is not as I expected as using loop to draw the graph, every time it will plot a NEW graph instant of plot on existing graph. Again, the code below work just fine.

```
int hist_w = 700; int hist_h = 700; //image size
void show_histogram(std::string const& name, cv::Mat1b const& image, cv::Mat &histImage)
{
double seconds = difftime( time(0), start);


  /// Establish the number of bins
  int histSize = 1000;

  /// Set the ranges 
  float range[] = { 0, 1000 } ;
  const float* histRange = { range };

  bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

  Mat hist;

  /// Compute the histograms:
  calcHist( &image, 1, 0, Mat(), hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );

  //Draw the histograms
  //int bin_w = cvRound( (double) hist_w/histSize );
   int bin_w = cvRound( (double) seconds);//x-axis



  /// Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ]
  normalize(hist, hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  /// Draw for points,for y-axis
  for( int i = 1; i < histSize; i++ )
  {
    Point ptPrev =  Point( bin_w*(seconds-1), hist_h - cvRound(hist.at<float>(0,255)));
    Point ptNew =    Point( bin_w*(seconds), hist_h - cvRound(hist.at<float>(0,255)));
    line( histImage,  ptPrev,ptNew,cv::Scalar::all(255), 5, 8, 0  );
    ptPrev = ptNew;
  }

  /// Display
   imshow(name, histImage);

 }

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

//On spot video 
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

Mat edges,gray;
  namedWindow("edges",1);
  Mat histImage( hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0,0,0) );
  for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera    
    imshow("Frame",frame);        
    cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(gray, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
    cv::namedWindow("edges",0);  
    cv::resizeWindow("edges", 100, 100);       
    imshow("edges", edges);
    show_histogram("White Pixel",edges);
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}

cv::waitKey();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: I cant understand what is your question. If the code works fine, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @A.Sarid I just include the image for my result in question above. As you can see, it is a point in the particular second. But I hope to draw a line. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: Are you calling this function once every X seconds? what is the value of `start`  in `double seconds = difftime( time(0), start)` ?

Comment: I calling this function using for(;;), and the start will be     time_t start = time(0); @A.Sarid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that every iteration of the `for(;;)` you mentioned in the comments you are creating a **new** `Mat histImage`.
You need to create it outside of the function, and pass it as an argument(by reference) to the function, make the changes and show the image.

Delete these lines from the body of the function, and put them outside the `for(;;)` loop:

```
int hist_w = 700; int hist_h = 700; //image size
Mat histImage( hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0,0,0) );
```

Change the function signature to be:

```
void show_histogram(std::string const& name, cv::Mat1b const& image, cv::Mat &histImage)
```

Comment: Can you show me the changes? Sorry but I am newbie for programming so it is more easy for me to study through examples. @A.Sarid

Comment: First, i am glad that my solution worked. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the check-mark. Regarding connecting the points - first, check your internal for loop that draws the line, I guess that this loop is useless as the value of `ptPrev` and `ptNew` is the same on every iteration. Instead of this. You should save the last point on every iteration of the external `for(;;)` loop and connect it with the new point.

Comment: How i can save the last point on every iteration of the external for(;;) loop and connect it with the new point? Sorry to being so newbie but I hope that you can guide me till the end and I would really appreciate that. By the way, already clicking the check-mark. =D

Comment: You can either save it as a global variable, or pass it to the function same way we did with the `Mat histImage`.

Comment: The "it" you mean will be the ptPrev and ptNew?

Comment: You need only the last one. yes.

Comment: Try for few hour but keep getting back the same thing, can you show me how you going to do it?

Comment: And how i plot the line if I only save the last point?
 line( histImage,  ptPrev,ptNew,cv::Scalar::all(255), 2, 8, 0  );